# java/android - How to guarantee if one thread or method is running, no one else can trigger it?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized

I'm working on android. Please help give any advice.
I have 3 methods(threads).

```
   Method_1 { trigger Method_3; ...}
   Method_2 { trigger Method_3; ...}
   Method_3 { ... }
```

How can I make sure that `Method_3` only can be triggered by `Method_1` or `Method_2`?
In other words, if `Method_1` is executed before `Method_2`, `Method_2` will skip to trigger `Method_3` if `Method_3` is still running. Or, If `Method_1` is executed before `Method_2`, `Method_2` will trigger `Method_3` if `Method_3` which is triggered by `Method_1` has been done.
The same question, how do I do in 3 threads like this ...

```
   Thread_1 { trigger Thread_3; ...}
   Thread_2 { trigger Thread_3; ...}
   Thread_3 { ... }
```

Because `Thread_3(Method_3)` is related to some global socket variable. I want to guarantee if this thread/method is running, no one else can trigger it because it is trying to connect to the other end on the network.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class variables to hold references to what method triggered what. Sounds like you need a reference to the method and a boolean state flag.

You can either use caching to store the result, preferences, or a global thats separated from the Activity, such as an async thread.

If the threads are managed from the same class, you can just use class variables that you store when destroyed in the savedInstance and load them back in onCreate.

Comment: It's really helpful! It works now! Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries, happy to ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use class with global and static variable to handle threads. if thread 3 triggered update variable in class to avoid any thread trigger it.
hope help you.

Comment: It's really helpful! It works now! Thank you for your help!